# A dropdown on Dash that returns values as option from the keys chosen by another dropdown

Tags: python, dropdown, plotly-dash

Basically there is a list of dictionary,
the first dropdown will have the option a/b/c from the keys of dict.

The question is how can I write the code to create another dropdown that gives options of the corresponding values based on the key of the dict chosen on the first dropdown?

e.g. If you choose 'a' on first first dropdown (among a, b, c), you are expected to see a1, a2, a3 on the second dropdown.

```
dict = {'a': [a1, a2, a3],
        'b': [b1, b2, b3],
        'c': [c1, c2, c3]}
```

```
app = Dash(__name__)
sidebar = html.Div(
    [
        html.H2("xyz note"),
        html.P(
            "Select a, b or c"
        ),
        dcc.Dropdown( list(dict.keys())),

        html.P(
            "Select the values"
        ),
        dcc.Dropdown(),

    ],
    style=SIDEBAR_STYLE,

)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on here https://dash.plotly.com/Basic-callbacks There is an article about chained callbacks. Firstly, you need to add the other dropdown in your app. layout. The app.callback (its function, respectively) should return the dropdown data selected by user. These data will serve as the input for a second dropdown in a second callback.